# What is the relation between Kruskal tensor and CP decomposition?

Tags: tensor, tensor-decomposition

In Matlab Tensor Toolbox there is a tensor type called "Kruskal tensors", I found its form is similar to the CP decomposition.

Wikipedia mentioned:

> "[As such, many of the methods have been independently invented
>   several times, often with subtle variations, leading to a confusing
>   literature. Abstract and general mathematical theorems are rare
>   (though see Kruskal[1] with regard to the CP decomposition)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition)"

In a [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.1796.pdf) on [*A concise proof of Kruskal's theorem on tensor decomposition*]， it mentioned:

> "...In these fields, the expression of a tensor as a sum of rank-1
>   tensors is often referred to as the Candecomp or Parafac
>   decomposition."

**So, what is the relation or difference between Kruskal tensor decomposition and [CP decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP_decomposition)?**

**Are they actually the same thing but Kruskal decomposition is devised by a different person in different field for third-order tensor?**